# How to create users for site from a web-form submission?

Tags: forms

I have added a webform into site to register a user, now i want users who added their information into form, to become a user of site .

Comment: There are lots of answers available. Try to use [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). You can't do this on your webform `<input type = "password">`.

Comment: no i did't want to duplicate form but want that after submiting form a user is created .

Comment: It's possible the best solution to your problem is not using the webform like you currently are but using the normal drupal user registration form in some way but to know that we need to know more about your requirement. What is the purpose of the webform? What data is it storing? What emails is it sending? etc.

Comment: i used drupal webform module to add form.Its a college site so the purpose of form is to store information of students and make them members for Alumni association .I want as they submit form they become member with login facility .

Comment: I have use Rule module but now i dont know how to use it ?